# how to use routerLink in HTML file in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

How to use routerLink in `.html` file? I have used below code but it is not working.

```
<div class="container">
<header class="page-header">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li routerLinkActive="active">
        <a [routerLink]="['/register']">Register<`/a>
    </li>
    <li routerLinkActive="active">
       <a [routerLink]="['/login']">Login</a>
    </li>        
  </ul>
</header>

<p class="jumbotron">
    <router-outlet><router-outlet>
</p>
```

In `app.component.ts` I have mentioned `templateUrl: 'index.html'`.

Comment: are You using dynamic routes??? cause `<a [routerLink]="['/register']">Register<`/a`

Answer (score 6):

From the [Official Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-links):

```
<div class="container">
<header class="page-header">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li>
        <a routerLink="/register" routerLinkActive="active">Register<`/a>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active">Login</a>
    </li>        
  </ul>
</header>

<p class="jumbotron">
    <router-outlet><router-outlet>
</p>
```

Also, did you set up your [imports](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-imports) and [routes](https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration) correctly?

Comment: Yes I imported. Your code also not working... If I add the same code in app.component.ts then it works fine... but i don't want to add my code there.

Comment: @ShailendraRPhadke `If I add the same code in app.component.ts then it works fine`... if it works fine one way and then not when you try to put it somewhere else, then it's something to do with your imports/configuration.

Comment: I have registered Login & RegisterComponent in app.module.ts,  & RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path: 'register',component:RegisterComponet},
      {path: 'login',component:LoginComponent}
    ])  what else?

Comment: you are correct. the same code if i write inside app.comoponent.ts it works fine...  But I don't want to add ALL my code here.. I want to use this code as a reference using templateUrl

Comment: If you want more help @ShailendraRPhadke you'll have to provide a [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with something like [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/)